# Give File Permission for modify in samba sharing but only owner can delete file

Tags: server, permissions, samba, acl

I need help regarding file permission in samba sharing,
**Is it possible to set an excel file in samba sharing (windows clients)** can be modified by group but only can be deleted by owner? I did follow some suggestion in some sources, it come to following samba config and ACL's, because we need to protect the file deletion from some users, the one that can delete will be only root:

```
    [ABC]
    path = /media/ABC
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    valid users = @ABC
    write list = @ABC
    force group = ABC
    create mode = 0664
    directory mode = 3775
```

with ACL's:

```
    root@svr:~# getfacl /media/ABC
    getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
    # file: media/ABC
    # owner: root
    # group: ABC
    # flags: -s-
    user::rwx
    group::rwx
    other::r-x

    root@svr:~# ls -l /media/ABC
    total 12
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 root ABC 8746 Nov 21 10:28 A.xlsx
```

I appreciate for any suggestions.